# Create a range of natural numbers with spread syntax

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, iterator

On the one hand, a lack of an equivalent to Python 3's `range` is an annoyance in ES6. On the other hand, there are lots of workarounds. My question is why one workaround I tried actually works. To illustrate:

```
[...Array(10).keys()];
```

In case the reason I find this mysterious is not obvious, note that `Array(10).keys()` is at least apparently empty.

I'm aware this wastefully creates two arrays, as do most of the popular workarounds, and, that (at the cost of creating a generator function) using a generator can avoid that. E.g.,

```
[...(function*(){let i = 0; while(i<10) yield i++;})()];
```

My question is only about why the first workaround produces the desired result.

**Edit:**

Judging from the answers, some people believe that the evaluation of `Array(10)` is equivalent to the evaluation of `Array.apply(null,Array(10))`.  They are not.  For example, `.hasOwnProperty(0)` is `false` for the former but `true` for the latter.  However, I am open to being persuaded they are the same in some way that matters here, since my understanding is clearly lacking at some key point.  I suspect that the answer is that the result of iterating over the keys is determine by the `length` property, which both share, rather than the actual array indexes that have been defined.  If so, I would like to know that this behavior is normative.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/keys

Comment: `.keys()` does return an *iterator*. It's not an array, it's not "apparently empty".

Comment: @Bergi  Take a look at it.  Like some of the answers, you seem to misunderstand what is produced by `Array(10)`.  (Or perhaps I misunderstand your answer.)

Comment: @Alan While `Array(10)` is indeed empty (not just apparently), `Array(10).keys()` is not - it's not an array.

Comment: @Bergi Of course.  That is the basis of the question: why is keys iterator over an *empty* array producing keys corresponding to the length?  (I.e., how does the spec lead us to expect this behavior?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`Array#keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/keys) returns an `Array` *iterator*. Spread syntax then completely exhausts that iterator by accessing the next value in the iterator until there are no more values. Then it collects all the values from the iterator and spreads them into a new array.

[`Array(10)`](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-array-len) creates an [array exotic object](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-array-exotic-objects) that does not have any actual integer-indexed keys, but just a `length` property -- so it would 'empty' but `Array(10).keys()` is not. The fact is that using `Array#keys` [doesn't depend on actual elements, just the length property](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.keys). The internal operation [CreateArrayIterator](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-createarrayiterator) creates a key iterator from an array by creating an iterator via the intrinsic [%ArrayIteratorPrototype% object](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-%arrayiteratorprototype%-object). Looking at [`%ArrayIteratorPrototype%.next()`](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-%arrayiteratorprototype%.next), you'll see that the length of the array is used. For `Array#keys` the index is continually incremented until it reaches the length of the array. That's how the iterator is created that gives you all the keys of the array without *actually having* said integer keys in the first place.

---

If you're curious about the abstract steps, see [Section 12.2.5.2 ArrayAcculumation](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-runtime-semantics-arrayaccumulation) of the ECMAScript Language Specification, particularly the *`SpreadElement : ... AssignmentExpression`* production which outlines the process of stepping through an iterator that is used in conjunction with spread syntax.

To see the abstract steps for collecting these values into a new array, see [Section 12.2.5.3 Evaluation](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-array-initializer-runtime-semantics-evaluation). Specifically, the *`ArrayLiteral : [ ElementList ]`* production is the production `[...Array.keys()]` falls under. The aforementioned ArrayAcculumation process is performed which aggregates iterates through the iterator and sets them into the new array.

Comment: You say "key iterator from an array by creating an iterator via the intrinsic `%ArrayIteratorPrototype%` object. Looking at `%ArrayIteratorPrototype%.next()`, you'll see that the `length` of the array is used."
That matches my speculation and answers my question.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

[Array.prototype.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/keys) is returning a new Array Iterator.
`Array(10)` is an array of 10 (**empty**) slots.

When you spread the array's keys, you are iterating over it and creating a new array. But this time the new array's items are the slots from the first array.

You can see it with `for of` loop:

```js
const arr = Array(10).keys();
for (let key of arr) {
  console.log(key);
}
```

By the way, you can use [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) which takes a [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function as it's second arguments. so you can just return the index or whatever you want:

```js
const arr = Array.from(Array(10), (_, idx) => idx);
console.log(arr);
```

**Edit**
As a followup to your edited question about the `Array(10)` result:
The [DOCS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Parameters) mentions:

> If the only argument passed to the Array constructor is an integer
>   between 0 and 232-1 (inclusive), this returns a new JavaScript array
>   with its length property set to that number (Note: this implies an
>   array of arrayLength empty slots, not slots with actual undefined
>   values). If the argument is any other number, a RangeError exception
>   is thrown.

So you actually get:

- A new array
- The length property is updated with the number provided to the
  function
- You get *n*-slots

Now `.keys` will create an Iterator, which will return each slot index as the value.
for example:

```
let it = Array(10).keys();
```

and calling:

```
it.next();
```

Will return:

```
{value: 0, done: false}
```

Calling it again and again will yield

```
{value: n, done: false}
```

up until it will get to the last slot:

```
{value: 9, done: false}
```

then the next `.next` call will return

```
{value: undefined, done: true}
```

which will flag that this is the end of the iterations.

running example:

```js
const it = Array(10).keys();
console.log(it.next());
console.log(it.next());
console.log(it.next());
console.log(it.next());
console.log(it.next());
console.log(it.next());
console.log(it.next());
console.log(it.next());
console.log(it.next());
console.log(it.next());
console.log(it.next()); // done: true
```

Answer (score 0):

`Array(10)` creates a length-10 array, each element of which is `undefined`.

`Array(10).keys()` returns an iterator, which iterates over the keys of the array...the numbers `0` through `9`.

When the spread syntax is used to define an array literal (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator), it fully-iterates any iterator it's given and adds the returns from the iterator to the created array (in order).

Comment: this: "_each element of which is undefined_" is not true actually. it creates an array with 10 **empty** slots. not `undefined`

Comment: I don't understand the distinction you're making here; could you say more? Each position in the array is a valid reference returning `undefined` as its value. Seems like they're in the same state as a variable that has been declared but not assigned.

Comment: first of all it's says so in the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Parameters) "_empty slots_". and as for the `undefined` that gets returned, you will get that with any index position: `Array(10)[99] === undefined`. well not any position really, the range is  between 0 and 232-1 (inclusive)